# "Яєшня" чи "яєчня"?

Tags: граматика, орфографія

У розмовній мові набагато частіше можна почути слово "яєшня", але, на мій погляд, звучить не надто грамотно. До того ж, приклади вживання слова "яєшня" пошукова система видає доволі застарілі.
Зокрема: *"Но хто лиш в город показався, того в яєшню і поб’ють". Котл. Ен. V. 72. Ум.*

У словниках же знайшла різне написання.
Так, [Тлумачний словник української мови](http://eslovnyk.com/%D1%8F%D1%94%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F) містить обидва слова: "яєшня" та "яєчня".

Аналогічна ситуація міститься у [Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/Jajechnja), де також застрічаються обива слова.

На моє здивування, я знайшла ще один варіант [на цьому сайті](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%AF%D1%94%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F) *- Яє́чниця, -ці, ж. = Яєшня.*

Подібне обговорення є [тут](https://ua-mova.livejournal.com/533420.html), але навіть там немає однозначної відповіді, тому маю надію нарешті з`ясувати це.

*У зв`язку з такою багатоманітністю чи то синонімів, чи то просто неправильних варіацій даного слова, виникає питання: яке з них (**"яєчня", "яєшня" чи "яєчниця"**) буде правильно вживати?* І чи не є слово "яєшня" застарілим?

Comment: Виходячи з того, як вчили мене у школі / університеті.

Comment: На жаль, не можу дати чіткого обгрунтування. Здається, головним аргументом на користь слова "яєчня" було те, що "яєшня" є застарілим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Завжди думала, що правильний варіант лише "яєЧня", а не "яєШня" і що при перекладі виникла помилка, проте натрапила на статтю «Оката яєчня, лАте, еспресо: найпоширеніші помилки у назвах їжі та напоїв» (сайту kava.lviv.ua, де була ця стаття, більше не існує, але статтю можна знайти [в інтернет-архіві](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926173020/http://kava.lviv.ua/ua/article/5863/%7Eokata-yajechnya-late-espreso-najposhyrenishi-pomylky-u-nazvakh-izhi-ta-napoiv), а також [під іншою назвою на сайті «1+1»](https://1plus1.ua/snidanok-z-1-1/novyny/late-chi-late-8-guchnih-pomilok-u-nazvah-napoyiv-ta-yizhi), звідки її імовірно й було взято сайтом kava.lviv.ua), в якій дає інтерв’ю Олександр Авраменко (яке також [доступне на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd2YNPSlZps&t=71s)). То ж Олександр Авраменко каже:

> *правильними* є обидва варіанти – *яєчня та яєшня*. Проте у словниках *«яєшня»* позначають як *застаріле слово*.

Comment: Відповідь містить посилання на не дійсний ресурс, що перенаправляє на підозрілий вебсайт. Публікація в інтернеті від автора зі статусом науковця не є науковою статтею. Посилання на таке джерело не можна вважати авторитетним і достатнім, щоб визнати відповідь на запитання вірною. Навіть якщо автор запитання вважає її прийнятною.

Comment: @Skill, я оновив застаріле посилання (і також дав пряме посилання на відповідний експрес-урок Авраменка). Звісно, авторитет Авраменка не безумовний (кожна людина може помилитися; хоча Авраменко згадує «словники», але не вточнює які саме й імовірно має на увазі той самий СУМ-11, про який уже знає автор запитання).

Answer (score 3):

Слово *яєчня* утворене від слова *яйце* (*яєць*) додаванням суфікса *-н-*. При цьому в корені також відбувається чергування *-ц-/-ч-*.

Слово *яєшня* утворене від слова *яєчня* [дисиміляцією *-ч-* в *-ш-*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85). Така дисиміляція загалом не є нетиповою для української мови (аналогічні випадків: *мірошник*, *рушник/рушниця*), хоча й відбувається рідко (є безліч аналогічних випадків, коли дисиміляція не відбулася: *маячня*, *помічник*, *річниця* тощо).

Оскільки в літературі зафіксовані обидва слова (наприклад у «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 16: *[яєчня](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=lemma&keyword=%D1%8F%D1%94%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F&showresults=1)*, *[яєшня](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=lemma&keyword=%D1%8F%D1%94%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F&showresults=1)*), я особисто не бачу причин відмовляти якомусь із них у праві на існування. Хоч у словниках, як уже було сказано, *яєшня* відмічене як розмовне.

Графік відносних частот вживань цих слів за роками згідно з даними ГРАК-16 має такий вигляд:
[image]
— тобто сильно домінувати *яєчня* почала тільки з 1940-х. Якщо брати трапляння лише до 1939 року (включно), то виходить, що *яєшня* траплялася вдвічі частіше за *яєчню*: [*яєчня* — 52](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%5Blemma%3D%22%D1%8F%D1%94%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%22%5D%20within%20%3Cdoc%20date%3C%3D%221939%22%2F%3E&showresults=1), [*яєшня* — 112](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%5Blemma%3D%22%D1%8F%D1%94%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%22%5D%20within%20%3Cdoc%20date%3C%3D%221939%22%2F%3E&showresults=1). Хоча наповненість ГРАКу за різні періоди нерівномірна, тож можливо, картина викривлена, бо за давні періоди просто недостатньо даних.